# How to reduce area boundaries resolution?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, zip-codes

I managed to plot zip codes boundaries for an entire US state using [ArcGIS](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=8d2012a2016e484dafaac0451f9aea24) data and python tools such as [arcpy](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000001000000) and [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/texas.html). The result:

[image]

The dataset has high resolution area boundaries so, I have like 2000 data points for each polygon and there are 1700 polygons. Thus, rendering 3.4 million data points approx. is very slow and the interface lags.

The questions is, do you know any methodology to reduce the area boundary resolution so the number of data points to be plotted is reduced? The resulting polygons should not overlap at all. Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a few ideas:

1. [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) using the simplify option - pretty sure this preserves topology, but you'd have to experiment with settings
2. http://mapshaper.org/ - online interactive simplification tool
3. Simplify tool in ArcGIS (it sounds like you have  that?)
4. Simplify Geometries tool in QGIS

I'm sure there are many more...

Comment: Simplify Polygon (Cartography) of Arcpy toolset is what I am currently using to accomplish the task. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//007000000011000000
Thank you very much!